# php codeigniter file_get_contents

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-get-contents

I'm currently working on a project that need `file_get_contents` function.
the problem I have right now is: how do I retrieve back the result i got from the `file_get_contents` url?

### the code

controller

```
public function send()
{

    $pokemon    = $this->input->post('username');
    $password   = $this->input->post('password');
    $siteaddressAPI = "http://host/wmc/receive/".$pokemon."/".$password."";
    $homepage = json_decode(file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI));
    if (! $homepage) {
        echo "failed";
    } else {
        echo $homepage;
    }
}
```

this is the code from file_get_contents controller

```
function receive($pokemon,$password)
{
    $this->load->model('m_wmc');

    //echo $pokemon .' - '. $password;
    $data= $this->m_wmc->get_member_data($pokemon,$password);
    $this->load->view('vw_wmc_bio',$data);

}
```

The question is how do I return the result of the receive function from the host to display the whole package including the view ?

I managed to display the result from the query.
Using this approach.

```
$this->load->model('m_wmc');

//echo $pokemon .' - '. $password;
$data= $this->m_wmc->get_member_data($pokemon,$password);
foreach ($data->result() as $key) {
    echo 'CUSTOMERID'   . ':' . $key->CUSTOMERID;
    echo 'CUSTOMER'     . ':' . $key->CUSTOMER;
    echo 'EMAIL'        . ':' . $key->EMAIL;
    echo 'ADDRESS'      . ':' . $key->ADDRESS;
    echo 'TELEPHONE'    . ':' . $key->TELEPHONE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your issue, you want to return the view content with your data.So you can simply achieve it by returning your data through view by passing an additional third parameter `TRUE` as follows :

```
$content = $this->load->view('vw_wmc_bio',$data, true);
return $content;
```

It will return you your view data as a string and you can further manipulate it as per your requirements. I hope it'll help you..!!

Comment: i've tried your solution, but it returned "failed", thanks for your the answer by the way

Comment: json_decode only works with json encoded data so you should pass your data to view and print encoded array of data only without any html tag or something else or you can achieve it by adding your data in array in your controller after that just print the json encoded form of your data and then put exit. It'll only return you the json encoded data to your file_get_content request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data in json format, you should return like that from receive function.

```
public function receive($pokemon,$password)
{  
    $this->load->model('m_wmc');

    //echo $pokemon .' - '. $password;
    $data= $this->m_wmc->get_member_data($pokemon,$password)->result_array();
    $jsonData = json_encode($data);
    header("Content-Length: ". sizeOf($jsonData));
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo $jsonData;
}
```

In your send function,

```
public function send()
{

    $pokemon    = $this->input->post('username');
    $password   = $this->input->post('password');
    $siteaddressAPI = "http://host/wmc/receive/".$pokemon."/".$password."";
    $homepageData = json_decode(file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI));
    $homepage = $this->load->view('vw_wmc_bio', $homepageData, true);
    if (! $homepage) {
        echo "failed";
    } else {
        echo $homepage;
    }
}
```